# DocuSign Webhook URL to Publish for Salesforce Listener Class

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have created a Listener class in Salesforce which should be called by DocuSign Connect. How is the Webhook URL created, what is the syntax and how the authentication happens when an event is fired ? Can Someone share a sample URL for HTTP Post type ?

Answer (score 0):

See this DocuSign blog post for setting up Docusign connect

[Adding Connect Webhooks to your Application](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/)

See the Docusign Connect for SalesForce Admin guide [Here](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/dfs-admin-guide/Content/admin-guide/ds-connect-for-salesforce.htm)

DocuSign connect will only Post to HTTPS listeners.

Comment: @CodingDawg- Thanks for your Feedback !! 
I have gone through the blog you shared and developed a Listener class (REST) on Salesforce which can catch HTTP POST request from WorkBench. Below is the url for the same.
"https://***.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account". 
How would be the Webhook URL looks like to call the Listener Class from DocuSign? What are the Parameters do we need to put in the URL? 
Do we need to put Salesforce Credentials in the Webhook URL? If not how Salesforce authenticates the incomming request ?

Comment: As we have multiple Salesforce instances i can not use DocuSign Standard connect. Hence i am going with DocuSign Custom Connect configuration. For this i need to configure the Webhook settings (especially Creating Webhook URL), where i got stuck badly :(